# convert rounded corner to right angel

Tags: graphics, coreldraw

I have found hundreds of post how to make a rounded corner, But I have something else.  I already have a rounded corner and I want to convert it back to right corner,
Currently I am using CorelDraw,

Any Idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

double click on the round area, right click on the nodes that's creates the rounded path. click convert to line.

If you have many nodes just delete all nodes around the rounded area as you don't need them any more and convert the rest points to line.